# How two threads can take lock on same object at a time?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I was reading Java Concurrency in Practice.

[image]

SO it is written that

`When  thread  A  executes  a  synchronized  block,  and  subsequently  thread  B  enters  a 
synchronized block guarded by the same lock`

How can two thread take lock on same object at a time?
Thanks.

Comment: thread A unlocks , then thread B enters and locks

Comment: keyword: subsequently.

Comment: They don't. The text and diagram are both very clear that the threads acquire them sequentially.

Comment: Sorry guys, i got confused with the subsequently word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"When  thread  A  executes  a  synchronized  block,  and  subsequently  thread  B  enters  a 
synchronized block guarded by the same lock" .

There will only be one lock. Thread B can get hold of the lock only when Thread A releases the lock. "`subsequently`". The author wants to say that the changes made by Thread A  on the same object will be visible to Thread B.

Answer (score 0):

They mean B enters lock after A released it

Answer (score 0):

Each object has lock. Just before a thread enters the synchronized block to execute the code, it acquires the lock. When the thread has finished executing the block, it releases the lock. The second thread cannot acquire the lock during this time. It acquires the lock once it has been released by the first thread.